# Find biggest number in JS array and return variable name

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do something very simple but I can't get it to work. I have 3 variables:

```
abc = 123
def = 456
ghi = 789
```

I created array like this:

```
numbers = [abc, def, ghi]
```

Then I did this:

```
Math.max.apply(null, numbers)
```

It returned 789, then I tried to do:

```
numbers.indexOf(789)
```

but it returns 2 = index of ghi, problem is I wanna find "ghi" name exactly and I am struggling.

Comment: Can you elaborate more what you are looking?

Comment: I want to return variable name so I can use it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the labels in your array as well. JavaScript is not able to read your variable name during your program's execution:

```js
const abc = 123;
const def = 456;
const ghi = 789;

const numbers = [
  {label: 'abc', value: abc},
  {label: 'def', value: def},
  {label: 'ghi', value: ghi}
];

const max = Math.max.apply(null, numbers.map(v => v.value));
console.log(max);

const maxObject = numbers.find(n => n.value === max);
console.log(maxObject.label);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use associative array then you dont need objects. here a sample solution using an array

```js
findMax = () => {
  // define the array
  let array = [];
  // filling items to the array
  array['a'] = 123;
  array['b'] = 456;
  array['c'] = 789;

  // variables for max and maxKey
  let max = 0;
  let maxKey = '';
  
  // iterate through the assoc array
  for (var key in array) {
    if(max <= array[key]){
      max = array[key];
      maxKey = key
     }
  }
  console.log('max key ' + maxKey + ' max value ' + max);
}
```

```html
<input type='button' onclick='findMax()' value='find max' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Object instead of Array.

```
const abc = 123;
const def = 456;
const ghi = 789;

const numbers = { abc, def, ghi };
const max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.values(numbers));
const [variableName] = Object.entries(numbers).find(([el, val]) => val === max);

console.log(variableName)
```

Solution

[image: Edit max variable name]

Answer (score 0):

As you have unique labels for values, I would define your data as an object. Then you can build a simple reducer to return the label and the value together:

```js
const numbers = {
  abc: 123,
  def: 456,
  ghi: 789
}

const [label, value] = Object.entries(numbers).reduce((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? a : b)
console.log(label, value)
```

The benefits of storing your variables in this way, is that you can quickly access your values by label simply by using `numbers['abc']` for example.